# (py)SDL2 & (py)OpenGL: mirror window contents

Tags: opengl, window, sdl, pyopengl, pysdl2

I'm using `pySDL2` to code an multi-monitor app where I'd like to have one fullscreen window on one display and a resized-down-by-two mirror of the fullscreen display in a window on the second display. I can do this easily with the standard `pySDL2` windows and the `pySDL2.ext` pixel access to copy the pixels from one window to the other (using `scipy.misc.imresize` to resize down in between), but I'd like to use `pyOpenGL` for drawing (to the fullscreen window at least) and can't seem to figure out how to do the same sort of copy-and-downsize to the second window when the first in an opengl context. I know I could use `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent` to switch to the second window's context and simply repeat any drawing done in the first window (rescaling as necessary), but keeping track of all the drawing seems like a lot of work. Can anyone suggest any better solutions?

Comment: You can render into a texture and then render that texture onto both windows. I think you will need to have two OpenGL contexts with shared ressources to make this work

Comment: Of course! Good call. Make yours an answer and I'll mark it correct :O)